# AttributeError 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'cv_results_'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm working through the `load_boston()` data for a scikit-learn tutorial. I'm running into this attribute error:

```
AttributeError 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'cv_results_'
```

Does anyone know if there is a bug? I am using 1.1.1 version of scikit-learn.

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler   
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV    
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

print(sklearn.__version__)

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)      

mod = KNeighborsRegressor().fit(X, y)     

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("scale", StandardScaler()),
    ("model", KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=3))  
    ])
print(pipe.get_params())  

mod1 = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid={'model__n_neighbors': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]},cv = 3)

pipe.fit(X, y)    
pred = pipe.predict(X)  
df = pd.DataFrame(mod1.cv_results_)   

plt.scatter(pred, y)  #pred instead of X
plt.title("Boston Housing Market")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Point is that `cv_results_` is an attribute of the *fitted* `GridSearchCV` instance, while you've only fitted the pipeline (its base estimator). Therefore, you should fit `mod1` to make it work.

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler   
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV    
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)      

mod = KNeighborsRegressor().fit(X,y)     

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("scale", StandardScaler()),
    ("model", KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=3))  
])
print(pipe.get_params())   
mod1 = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe,param_grid={'model__n_neighbors': 
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]},cv = 3)
mod1.fit(X, y)

df = pd.DataFrame(mod1.cv_results_)
```

Be aware, though, that method `.fit()` of `GridSearchCV` does not return the fitted base estimator (despite fitting it, of course). Therefore, you won't be able to call `pipe.predict(X)` if you just substitute `pipe.fit(X, y)` via `mod1.fit(X, y)`.